# Update the position of a shape created with extrudePath in three.js

Tags: three.js

Using three.js, given two points, I am generating a 3D shape.

```
 function shapeMesh(pointX, pointY) {

    var extrudeSettings = {steps:2};

    //create base shape
    var pts = []

    //I beam shape
    var f = 100;
    var w = 100 / f;
    var h = 150 / f;
    var tf = 10 / f;
    var tw = 10 / f;

    pts.push(new THREE.Vector2(tw, 0));
    pts.push(new THREE.Vector2(tw, h - tf));
    pts.push(new THREE.Vector2(w, h - tf));
    pts.push(new THREE.Vector2(w, h));
    pts.push(new THREE.Vector2(0, h));
    pts.push(new THREE.Vector2(-w, h));
    pts.push(new THREE.Vector2(-w, h - tf));
    pts.push(new THREE.Vector2(-tw, h - tf));
    pts.push(new THREE.Vector2(-tw, 0));

    pts.push(new THREE.Vector2(tw, -h + tf));
    pts.push(new THREE.Vector2(w, -h + tf));
    pts.push(new THREE.Vector2(w, -h));
    pts.push(new THREE.Vector2(0, -h));
    pts.push(new THREE.Vector2(-w, -h));
    pts.push(new THREE.Vector2(-w, -h + tf));
    pts.push(new THREE.Vector2(-tw, -h + tf));

    var starShape = new THREE.Shape(pts);

    //create target point/spline
    var randomPoints = [];
    randomPoints.push(pointX);
    randomPoints.push(pointY);

    var randomSpline = new THREE.SplineCurve3(randomPoints);
    extrudeSettings.extrudePath = randomSpline;

    var circle3d = starShape.extrude(extrudeSettings);
    return addGeometry(circle3d, 0xff1111, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

And the addGeometry function is the following:

```
    function addGeometry(geometry, color, x, y, z, rx, ry, rz, s) {
    // 3d shape
    var mesh = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject(geometry, [ new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color:color, opacity:0.2, transparent:true }), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color:0x000000, wireframe:true, opacity:0.3 }) ]);

    mesh.position.set(x, y, z);
    mesh.scale.set(s, s, s);

    return mesh;
}
```

Everything works and it looks lovely, however when I try to update its position, using `.setPosition(x,y,z)` the whole object is being moved relative to the (x,y,z) points, and so far I can't figure out which is the correct way to recalculate the position using start / end points like in the functions above.

If someone could lead me to the correct solution, I would much appreciate it :)

Comment: Have you tried adding to another object and moving that object?

Comment: The object itself is being moved, but relatively to the (x,y,z) coords. What I want is for the whole shape to be redrawn. I ended up deleting the shape and drawing it again, which may be the correct solution after all!